# OpenGL strange circle appears in blank window

Tags: c++, opengl

I've managed to create the black window as described in [lesson 1](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/), but i also get a strange circle object displayed in the bottom of the window. If i draw the triangle from [lesson 2](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/), this circle does not disappear, it is still visible behind the white triangle.

[image]

Help me to get rid of this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <gl\glfw3.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>

int main(){
    int openGlMainVersion = 3;
    int openGlSubVersion = 3;
    int antiAliasingSamples = 4;
    int windowWidth = 1920;
    int windowHeight = 1080;

if (!glfwInit())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, antiAliasingSamples);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, openGlMainVersion);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, openGlSubVersion);

GLFWwindow* window;
window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "OpenGL Level 1", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "FAiled to open opengl window. Version:");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
do{

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's just not enough information in the question to help.  We have no idea what your code does, or what it's supposed to be doing.  *Short* code samples are great, if they can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Dietrich, did you look at the picture?  It looks too non-trivial for it to have only happened to the op.  I bet someone knows exactly what it is, is all I'm saying.

Comment: I use almost the exact same code that you can find in the tutorial. I've added it to the description.

Comment: @Carl: Right, it's non-trivial.  But that doesn't change the fact that there wasn't enough good information in the question.

Comment: The only thing that I can think it's that you need to call clear buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not have any OpenGL draw calls... it doesn't even have any OpenGL calls whatsoever!  Ordinarily, you would at least call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` once each frame, even if you don't do anything else.

If you don't draw anything to the screen, you may get whatever garbage happened to be in the framebuffer that your OpenGL implementation gave you (depending... this never happens in WebGL, for example).